# Cmake on macOS error: Could not find MySQL headers

Tags: azerothcore

When running the cmake command in order to compile [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/) on macOS Mojave, I'm using the parameteres:

```
-DMYSQL_ADD_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include
-DMYSQL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dylib
```

however the cmake fails with the following error:

> CMake Error at src/cmake/macros/FindMySQL.cmake:179 (message):   Could
>   not find MySQL headers! Please install the development libraries and
>   headers Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:93
>   (find_package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by installing and linking `mysql56` with brew:

`brew install mysql56`

`brew link mysql56 --force`